# What is the fastest way to write a byte array to a file?

Tags: java, file

What is the fastest way for creating a file and writing a byte array of over 100 MB in datasize into it?

Comment: Where's that related topic?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fastest"? Coding-wise the easiest way to achieve this or the actual writing performance? Do you want to write many small files or one huge file? Please provide more details on this question.

Comment: @DaDaDom sorry, I had to tell more details, a huge file (>100M)

Comment: 100M is not a huge file.

Comment: fastest way means the writing procedure doesn't last much time

Comment: What were your own results when you tested the various ways of writing files?

Comment: @J.Steen the methods which use a buffer and reduce I/O operation act faster

Comment: If you knew that, why did you ask the question? My point is, when benchmarking, do it yourself first.

Comment: @J.Steen yes, you are true, but I'd like to know others ideas and experiences, maybe there is a note which I'm not mentioning...

Comment: You can write 100 MB in less than a second.  As low as 20 milli-seconds on some systems.

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you please explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a FileOutputStream, write the bytes, close the stream in a finally block (or use the Java 7 try-with-resources).

Comment: If you have these 100M in memory and write the whole byte array in a single call, it couldn't be faster. If you write the file byte by byte, or very small chunk by very small chunk, then the answer is different, and a BufferedOutputStream would be helpful.

Comment: +1 the only way which is faster it to not build a huge array in memory in the first place.  If you write data out progressively it can be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

[`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);`](http://goo.gl/xBziD)

Answer (score 0):

While the standard `java.io` classes are still very popular, I would also try the new IO mechanism in `java.nio` (and the [`FileChannels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)). They provide a little bit lower-level file access and may be more efficient.